# Wrong template rendering

Tags: django

I don't understand why django wont render any other template , but home with this code:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/', login_page),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^contact/', contact_page),
    url(r'^about/', about_page),
    url(r'$', home_page),
]
```

But as soon as I delete the home url , every url works just fine. Yes , I did join the base dir with the templates one. Also , it might be useful to add that Im using django 1.11. Thank you !

Comment: I think the home URL should have the ^ before the $.

Comment: Yes , it works perfectly, for some reason I was confident that was the regex syntax, thank you so much !